# Recursive Guessing Game

Tags: python, recursion

Im using python 3.4 and I am trying to make a recursive guessing game. The game should take a min value and a max value and have a "magic" number. The game is going to generate a random number in between the range of x and y. Then ask the user to insert y for yes l for too low, and h for too high. if it is yes 'congratulations message', then exit. if it is too low, take the min val x, and add 1 to it and that will be the new min value. Same logic for h too high. Then re generate random number. Im getting stuck on where to call the recursion.

```
def recursive_guess(x,y,):
correct = False
while not correct:

    print('I will guess a number y for yes, l for too low, h for too high')
    guess = random.randrange(x, y)
    print(guess)
    anwser = input('y for yes l for low h for high')
    if anwser == 'y':
      print('Got it right')
      correct = True
    elif anwser == 'l':
      guess = random.randrange(minVal + 1, maxVal)
   elif anwser == 'h':
     guess = random.randomrange(minVal, maxVal-1)
```

Comment: Why are you using recursion?  This is a basic exercise in iterative loops, and it's not really a recursive problem, since we allow the user to control the boundaries.

Comment: He's probably practicing recursion, there's nothing wrong with that.  Also it's a fine problem for recursion.  "It's not really a recursive problem" is just your opinion, it's kind of pointless to argue.

Answer (score 0):

Let's switch to high-level pseudocode and give your variables better names, because I think you're getting caught up in the syntactic details and don't have the big picture of your algorithm in your head yet.

```
def recursive_guess(lower_bound, upper_bound):
  guess = random guess in range [lower_bound, upper_bound]
  print guess
  request user response
  response = <get user response>
  if guess was too high:
    upper_bound = guess - 1
  elif guess was too low:
    lower_bound = guess + 1
  else:
    return guess
  # assuming we reached this point without returning,
  # we need to do a recursive call because guess was wrong
  return recursive_guess(lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

In your code given, you seem to have started off with a recursive approach, but then you switched (subconsciously) to the iterative approach as soon as you updated your guess again to a new random value.  If you do the same thing at the end of your function as you did at the beginning, that can suggest to you that you possibly should have already recursed.

Think of recursion as simply making your task slightly smaller, and then you are already done.  In this case, if we can reduce the window size (`upper_bound - lower_bound`) then we have done our job.  The recursion will take care of it from there, as long as we have a base case in place.  In this scenario, the base case is guessing correctly, in which case we return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `guess = random.randrange(minVal + 1, maxVal)`, you should change minVal and then use it, like this:

```
minVal = guess + 1
guess = random.randrange(minVal, maxVal)
```

Otherwise, minVal and maxVal will not close in on the correct number; the guesses in the elif statements will be the same every time, since minVal and maxVal are not actually changed. Also, I'm not seeing where minVal and maxVal are set to x and y.

Edit: not sure where the recursiveness comes in. If you want to make this function recursive, you could take it out of the while loop and have it call itself, ie `recursive_guess(guess + 1, y)` instead of the lines above.